# jQuery filter, return different jQuery object (i.e. $(this).parent() )

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, filter

I'm trying to return an object of all subelements (of, for example 'body' - i.e. a large chunk of / all of the DOM) that contain text (other than whitespace). The following works very well:

```
function findAllSubnodesWithText( el ) {
  // find all subnodes that don't have subnodes themselves
  return $(el).find("*:not(:has(*))").filter(function ( ) {
    return $(this).text().trim().replace('\n', '').length > 0;
  });
}
```

Except that it trips up on nodes like the one below (div.headline has three subnodes: text, br, text). It means that nothing at all from the div comes through into my findAllSubnodesWithText() result

```
<div id="base_node">
 <p>some text in a p tag</p>
 <div>
  <div class="headline"> 
  Here is some headline text split by a <br>
  line break
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

So I want to do something like this:

```
function findAllSubnodesWithText( el ) {

  return $(el).find("*:not(:has(*))").filter(function ( ) {
    if( this.nodeName == "BR" ) {
      return $(this).parent();
    } else {
      return $(this).text().trim().replace('\n', '').length > 0;
    }
  });
}
```

But obviously the filter is just testing whether the a parent exists, adding the BR to the result object. Also, if there's more than one `<br>` it'd be nice to avoid having the same parent twice in the result.

So what I'd like to have at the end is this:

```
var result = findAllSubnodesWithText('#base_node')
$(result[0]).text() = "some text in a p tag"
$(result[1]).text() = 
 "Here is some headline text split by a
line break"
```

Comment: Can you provide another example(s) regarding what should be selected and what should not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to find all text nodes that are not empty and return their parents:

```
function findAllSubnodesWithText(el) {
    return $(el)
        .find("*")  // using .find instead of a recursive function
        .contents() // filter out text nodes that are not-empty (this and below)
        .filter(function () {
            return this.nodeType === this.TEXT_NODE && $.trim(this.data).length > 0
        })
        .parent();  // get parent
}

var $a = findAllSubnodesWithText(document.body);
console.log($a);

// returns
// [p, div.headline]
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/zfhw3/)

Comment: Great! The .parent() at the end was the part of the logic that I didn't get.

I actually still don't understand why it works. Does jQuery map .parent() for every result of the filter once it's filtered? I didn't realise you could have a list of jQuery objects and run .parent() on all of them... jQuery is a clever beast.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that?

```
function findAllSubnodesWithText(el) {
    // find all subnodes that don't have subnodes themselves
    return $(el).contents().filter(function () {
        return !$(this).children().length && $(this).text()
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**
I'm quite confused for what you are looking for exactly (subnodes without subnodes seems contradicted by what your example gives), anyway:

```
function findAllSubnodesWithText(el) {
    return $(el).contents().filter(function () {
        return  $.trim($(this).text())
    }).map(function(){
        return $.trim($(this).text())
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! interesting idea with .contents(), I didn't realise it returns an array-like object like that. unfortunately it only looks one level deep. have a look at the updated question for my desired output

Comment: Thank you for the idea with .map(), I hadn't used it before.